# Shall I integrate Stripe payment with app or website?

Tags: android, ios, web, stripe-payments, payment

I am building an app across iOS and Android mobile phones which processes payment functions and I decide to use Stripe.
I am wondering what is the best practice before coding. I could potentially create native panel in the app to present the payment page and let the app to send payment details to Stripe, or alternatively, build a web page on my web server with the following example code to do the payment

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
    class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-image="/square-image.png"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-amount="2000">
  </script>
</form>
```

As I am very new to Stripe and payment world, I am not sure which approach is the best way?

From the design point of view I can tell embed a web page based payment page can be reused across Android and iOS, and easier to build, however, from the user experience point of view I understand a native payment page will be better.

My question is, apart from user experience, is there any downside of web paged solution (Such as security)? Or which approach will you use?

Thank you.

Comment: Do your iOS and Android apps connect to your own backend server/API to process the order e.g. save the order to the DB?